# How to insert a record into a table

Tags: postgresql

I'm using *plpgsql* to do this but get the error

***record type has not been registered***

This is as simple as

```
declare
  myrecord RECORD;
begin
  SELECT myrow as "myrow" INTO myrecord FROM (SELECT 1, 2);
  INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2)
  VALUES (myrecord.*);
end;
```

Could please anybody help?
My postgres version is 8.4

Comment: What's wrong with: `INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2) values (1,2)`? Or if it **must** be based on a select `INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2)
  select 1,2`;

Comment: Must be based, cause the sample is not the real case.
In the real case, record is extracted from a query.
I want to preserve record structure for query output rather than use query itself for the INSERT sentence.

Answer (score 0):

There are two valid ways to do this.  The first is:

```
begin
  INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2)
  VALUES (1, 2);
end;
```

The second is:

```
begin
  INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2)
  SELECT 1, 2;
end;
```

Naturally these do not need to be in pl/pgsql blocks.

BTW, in the psql tool, you can do `\h insert` to get a list of valid insert forms.  These are the synposes from the manual and it's one thing that makes the tool so helpful.

Comment: You seem solving the sample, not the question.
Target is using a record.